# automatically backup before revert

Tags: backup, revert-buffer, auto-revert-mode, global-auto-revert-mode

I would like to backup buffers before they are (auto) reverted.

This is nontrivial because the file a buffer is visiting isn't current, and the backup system normally works by duplicating the file the buffer visits.

Comment: I think we can run undo to go back to the version before auto-revert.

Comment: That seems unpleasant because the process would be (revert, undo, save buffer, backup, redo the revert, save buffer), which doesn't seem entirely safe.